# How to write this SQL statement?

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is the table:
User

```
Name:  Subject:
Peter   Math
Mary    Chinese
Mary    Computer
Mary    Hist
Mary    PE
Mary    English
Peter   Art
Chris   English
Chris   Computer
Peter   Computer
Paul    Math
```

I would like to get the the top appear in name, and return top 4 result should be subject name. For example, in this case top appear name is Mary, and base on the order in subject, the Chinese , Computer, English, so I would like to have the result:

```
Mary    Chinese
Mary    Computer
Mary    English
Mary    Hist
```

If Mary is not the most enough to show the result, the second people will be the follow, like, let say the table will like this:

```
Name:  Subject:
Peter   Math
Mary    Chinese
Mary    Computer
Mary    Hist
Peter   Art
Chris   English
Chris   Computer
Peter   Computer
Paul    Math
```

The result will be,

```
Mary    Chinese
Mary    Computer
Mary    Hist
Peter   Art
```

Because Mary is the most appear, so Mary will return, but Mary is not enough to fill in 4 positions, so the second most appear will take the place, in this case, we use Peter.

Comment: @Martin, yes Note that `peter` and `chris` are tied for 2nd place.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT user.name, user.subject
FROM user
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT name, COUNT(1) AS occurrences
    FROM user
    GROUP BY name
  ) AS user_occurrences
  ON user.name = user_occurrences.name
ORDER BY user_occurrences.occurrences DESC, user.name ASC, user.subject ASC
LIMIT 4
```

**edit** This might perform better, depending on the RDBMS you're using and the size of the dataset. Try both and compare.

```
SELECT user.name, user.subject
FROM user
INNER JOIN user AS user_occurrences
  ON user.name = user_occurrences.name
GROUP BY user.name --, user.subject Second GROUP BY not needed on MySQL, but it should logically be there
ORDER BY COUNT(user_occurrences.subject) DESC, user.name ASC, user.subject ASC
LIMIT 4
```

Comment: Hmm... I'm not sure either now :P I think I misread something... let me check

Comment: You're right, edited (pointed at someone who seems to have deleted his comment?)

Comment: Even if its not, the subquery I added there isn't needed. For some reason, dunno why, I thought that the first 4 subjects should be returned per user with multiple users (the first 4 subjects of Marry followed by the first 4 subjects of John, etc). But I did add an LIMIT 4 to the whole thing... not quite sure why I did that

Comment: Edited to sort by subject name

Comment: I think the ORDER BY should be extended like this: `ORDER BY COUNT(user_occurrences.subject) DESC, user.name ASC, user.subject ASC`, that is, `user.name ASC` should be added just after the number of occurrences.

Comment: You're right, it could give mixed results in case of ties. Updated. Thanks

Comment: @shesek, you are using LEFT JOIN (out of habit perhaps), this should really be a INNER JOIN, and for performance reasons you should drop the 2nd group by in MySQL (pull it inside the comment).

Comment: @Johan, you're right - I did a LEFT JOIN because I was thinking about a case where a user had no subjects and he's still on the top... which makes absolutely no sense in this schema (/me has been awake and coding for ~30 hours). And I'm used to Postgres, where you are (rightfully) forced to GROUP BY every field that's used outside an aggregate function. MySQL behavior on this one is just weird IMHO... but I'll change that too

Comment: The MySQL allowence for sloppy group by clauses is a performance hack. If the field is fully dependent on another `group by` parameter, than it is not useful to explicitly specify that field in the group by clause, because it will slow things down without changing the outcome. You and most other DB's are right that this allowance has a lot a abuse potential,, but so has the select `max(field_avoided_in_group_by_clause)` workaround that is forced upon people in non-MySQL databases.

Comment: IIRC the performance hit on PostgreSQL for `GROUP BY`ing on columns that doesn't actually group anything is very small, it knows how to handle those cases

Comment: Nope. I didn't remember correctly. Adding some benchmarks and refactoring to my todo :-)

Comment: the result is very strange. Doesn't match the first one, same table, same data.

Answer (score 1):

select top 4 from group by Name, Subject and sort by count

MSSQL Code:

```
select top 4 q.marketname, cc.countryname from (
select top 100  m.MarketName, m.MarketId, COUNT(m.marketname) as [count]  
from Common.Country c inner join Common.Market m on c.MarketId = m.MarketId
group by m.MarketName, m.MarketId order by COUNT(m.marketname) desc) 
q inner join Common.Country cc
on cc.MarketId = q.MarketId order by [Count] desc
```

You can make similar mySQL code

Here is relevent MySQL Code

```
select q.name, cc.subject from (
  select m.Name, count(*) as Count
  from User m
  group by m.Name 
  order by COUNT(*) desc 
  LIMIT 100
) q 
inner join user cc on cc.Name= q.name 
order by Count desc 
LIMIT 4
```

This is weired, you want solution with no effort? Can't you implemet logic in your technology? You should not downvote without understanding solution suggested.

Comment: As pseudo code it doesn't work either. grouping by `name,subject` is wrong. It needs a group by name then a join back for example though there may well be more efficient ways.

Comment: Your code has no relation with the question: different SQL-server, different column names, the top 100 in the inner select makes no sense, it should be top 4. If I was a noob, I'd a hard time converting this code into working MySQL code.

Comment: @johan, This is weired, you want solution with no effort? Can't you implemet logic in your technology? You can convert to mySQL simply by removing `top 4` from the query and adding `limit 4` at the end of query. You want me to do that?

Comment: The differences between MySQL and TSQL are more substantial than just the `TOP -> LIMIT`. I downvoted the first one, because I thought the answer was too far off the question to be useful esp. in case the OP would be a newbie (which may or may not be the case)