# How can I implement this in active record?

Tags: php, codeigniter, activerecord

I would like to transfer this question to active record:

The SQL statement I would like to transfer:

```
SELECT user.name, user.subject
FROM user
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT name, COUNT(1) AS occurrences
    FROM user
    GROUP BY name
  ) AS user_occurrences
  ON user.name = user_occurrences.name
ORDER BY user_occurrences.occurrences DESC, user.name ASC, user.subject ASC
LIMIT 4
```

[How to write this SQL statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7268973/how-to-write-this-sql-statement)

I can join table, but how can I create a new table in the active record? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Active Record class has very limited capabilites. Other than writing the sub-query inside the join method, there's not much that you can do.

Comment: @@" why the active record so limited.